Oracle procedure giving multiple syntax errors
I have written a stored procedure to update 2 tables with some IF ELSE conditions. But while compiling the full procedure I am getting syntax error:
Error 1:

Error(1115,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:     ; is with default authid as cluster order using external    deterministic parallel_enable pipelined result_cache    accessible rewrite

Error 2:

Error(1217,23): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     end not pragma final instantiable persistable order    overriding static member constructor map

Below is my SP
PROCEDURE APPROVED_BY_CMM_OL
(
PJOB_PROGRESS_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.JOB_PROGRESS_ID%TYPE,
PSTATUS_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.STATUS_ID%TYPE,
PHOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.HOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE%TYPE,
PLIT_ACCEPTENCE_DATE IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.LIT_ACCEPTENCE_DATE%TYPE,
PAPPROVED_BY IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.APPROVED_BY%TYPE,
PREJECTED_BY IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.REJECTED_BY%TYPE,
PAPPROV_REJECT_REMARK IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.APPROV_REJECT_REMARK%TYPE,
PMODIFIED_BY IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.MODIFIED_BY%TYPE,
PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID%TYPE,
PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME%TYPE,
PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID%TYPE,
PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME%TYPE,
PHOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.HOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH%TYPE,
PLIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH IN TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.LIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH%TYPE,
POUTMSG OUT NVARCHAR2
)

SELECT DISTINCT JOB_ID INTO VJOB_ID
  FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS
  WHERE JOB_PROGRESS_ID = PJOB_PROGRESS_ID;


IF PSTATUS_ID = 4 OR PSTATUS_ID = 10 OR PSTATUS_ID = 11 THEN

                UPDATE TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS
                       SET HOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE = TO_DATE (PHOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
      APPROVED_BY   = PAPPROVED_BY,
      APPROVED_DATE =
      CASE
        WHEN PAPPROVED_BY IS NULL
        THEN NULL
        ELSE SYSDATE
      END,
      REJECTED_BY           = NULL,
      REJECTED_DATE         = NULL,
      APPROV_REJECT_REMARK  = PAPPROV_REJECT_REMARK,
      MODIFIED_BY           = PMODIFIED_BY,
      MODIFIED_DATE         = SYSDATE,
      UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID   = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID,
      UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME,
      UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID   = NULL,
      UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME = NULL,
      UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_DATE = SYSDATE,
      JOB_PROGRESS_FLAG     = 1,
      STATUS_ID             = PSTATUS_ID,
      HOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH    = PHOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH,
      LIT_ATCUAL_LENGTH     = PLIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH,
      HOTO_OFFER_LEN_UPD_BY = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME,
     -- IS_PARTIAL            = P_ISPARTIAL,
      NE_SPAN_LENGTH        = P_NELENGTH
    WHERE JOB_PROGRESS_ID   = PJOB_PROGRESS_ID;
    
UPDATE TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS
    SET JOB_FLAG                = 1,
      MAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH = P_NELENGTH
    WHERE JOB_ID                = VJOB_ID;
    POUTMSG                    := 'SUCCESS|HOTO process completed and Request closed';    




ELSE
    UPDATE TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS
    SET HOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE = TO_DATE (PHOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
      APPROVED_BY   = PAPPROVED_BY,
      APPROVED_DATE =
      CASE
        WHEN PAPPROVED_BY IS NULL
        THEN NULL
        ELSE SYSDATE
      END,
      REJECTED_BY           = NULL,
      REJECTED_DATE         = NULL,
      APPROV_REJECT_REMARK  = PAPPROV_REJECT_REMARK,
      MODIFIED_BY           = PMODIFIED_BY,
      MODIFIED_DATE         = SYSDATE,
      UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID   = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_ID,
      UMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME,
      UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID   = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_ID,
      UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_NAME,
      UMS_GROUP_ASS_TO_DATE = SYSDATE,
      JOB_PROGRESS_FLAG     = 1,
      STATUS_ID             = PSTATUS_ID,
      HOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH    = PHOTO_ACTUAL_LENGTH,
      LIT_ATCUAL_LENGTH     = PLIT_ACTUAL_LENGTH,
      HOTO_OFFER_LEN_UPD_BY = PUMS_GROUP_ASS_BY_NAME,
      --IS_PARTIAL            = P_ISPARTIAL,
      NE_SPAN_LENGTH        = P_NELENGTH
    WHERE JOB_PROGRESS_ID   = PJOB_PROGRESS_ID;


SELECT JB.SPAN_ID, JB.LINK_ID, JB.MAINTENANCEZONECODE, JB.MAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH,JB.SPAN_TYPE
    INTO VSPAN_ID, VLINK_ID, VMAINTZONECODE, JOB_NE_LENGTH,VSPAN_TYPE
    FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS JB
    WHERE JB.JOB_ID = VJOB_ID;
    
    IF 1 = 1 THEN
      --            BEGIN
      UPDATE TBL_FIBER_INV_JOBS
      SET MAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH = P_NELENGTH,
        JOB_FLAG                    = 0
      WHERE JOB_ID                  = VJOB_ID;
      
      UPDATE TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS
      SET NE_SPAN_LENGTH = P_NELENGTH
      WHERE JOB_ID       = VJOB_ID;
      
      POUTMSG           := 'SUCCESS|HOTO process partially completed';
    END IF;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  ERROR_CODE    := SQLCODE;
  ERROR_MESSAGE := SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 200);
  ROLLBACK;
  POUTMSG := 'ERROR|Error occurred on record updation';
  PKG_FIBER_HOTO_COMP_NEW.INS_ERRORLOG('','','DB : APPROVED_BY_CMM_OL',ERROR_CODE||' : '||ERROR_MESSAGE);
  
END APPROVED_BY_CMM_OL;

where am I going wrong?

This seems to be part of a package and you haven't said how the line numbers in the messages relate to the code you've provided. But you're missing IS (or AS) - which the first error includes in its list of 'expected' things - and BEGIN before the first SELECT.

@AlexPoole: yes it’s a part of package.. can you help me what exactly needs to be included ?

Huh? I already have? You have PROCEDURE APPROVED_BY_CMM_OL (...), add IS BEGIN before SELECT. This is standard structure for a stored procedure.

Ok let me try and check

You are missing part of the basic structure of a subprogram. As the first error message says, it's expecting something before SELECT, and the list of possibilities includes IS. You are also missing the BEGIN, which in this case comes next as you don't need to declare any local variables.
So it should be:
PROCEDURE APPROVED_BY_CMM_OL
(
...
)
IS
BEGIN

SELECT DISTINCT JOB_ID INTO VJOB_ID
  FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS
  WHERE JOB_PROGRESS_ID = PJOB_PROGRESS_ID;
...

Well, I say you don't need to declare any local variables, but you refer to some VJOB_ID etc. - so if those are not package variables (and they probably shouldn't be as that introduces state) you will need to declare those:
PROCEDURE APPROVED_BY_CMM_OL
(
...
)
IS
  VJOB_ID TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS.JOB_ID%TYPE;
  -- and others used in later select
BEGIN

SELECT DISTINCT JOB_ID INTO VJOB_ID
  FROM TBL_FIBER_INV_JOB_PROGRESS
  WHERE JOB_PROGRESS_ID = PJOB_PROGRESS_ID;
...

fiddle
The second error looks like a structural error elsewhere, maybe missing the final END for the package. From the line numbers I think that is the problem, so your package probably currently ends with:
END APPROVED_BY_CMM_OL;
/

instead of:
END APPROVED_BY_CMM_OL;
END;
/

or:
END APPROVED_BY_CMM_OL;
END <package_name>;
/

In general, fix one error at a time, see what - if anything - it complains about on next compilation attempt. And it is often easier to spot structural mistakes if you format and indent your code consistently.

I added AS at the start of the procedure, but now getting only one error as Error(1221,23): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     begin end function pragma procedure 

So... did you addd BEGIN as well? If you did then the remaining error is probably elsewhere in your package.
